# Any compact subspace of $C([a,b])$ in the sup-norm is uniformly equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

Show that any compact subspace of $C([a,b])$ in the sup-norm is uniformly equicontinuous. I read through this link

[Show that any compact subset of $C([0,1])$ with sup norm is equicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531265/show-that-any-compact-subset-of-c0-1-with-sup-norm-is-equicontinuous)

but I'm confused by some steps. First, how does proving $F \subset A_{l}$ prove equicontinuity. Second, how does the union of $A_n$ over all $n$ form a cover?

Answer (score 0):

First, if $F\subset A_l$, by definition of $A_l$ for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists  $\delta=\frac{1}{l}$, which depends only on $\epsilon$,  such that
$$|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$
for all $f\in A_l$ thus for all $f\in F$. This is definition of equicontinuity.

Second, for any $f\in C[0,1]$, since $f$ is continuous, f is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. By definition, there exists an $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that
$$ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon
$$
Choose $n_0>\frac{1}{\delta}$, then $f\in A_{n_0}$.

For $A_n$ is open:
Let $f\in A_n$, we need to show there exists an $\delta>0$, such that
for all $g$ satisfying $\|f-g\|<\delta$, we have $g\in A_n$.This is because
$$ |g(x)-g(y)|\leq|g(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-g(y)|<2\delta+|f(x)-f(y)|
$$
since $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, we can choose $\delta$ small such that
$$ |g(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-g(y)|<\epsilon
$$
Well, this is not true, because $\delta$ depends on $x$ and $y$.

I don't think $A_n$ is open,  for $n=1$, $\epsilon=1$, let $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=(1+\delta)x-\delta/2$. Then $\|g-f\|=\delta/2$
$$ |g(x)-g(y)|=(1+\delta)|x-y|
$$
For any $\delta>0$, we can always find $|x-y|<1$ such that
$$ (1+\delta)|x-y|>1
$$
So $A_1$ with $\epsilon=1$ couldn't be open. If $n$ is large or $\epsilon$ is small, we can use scaling to construct counterexamples

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation. How is $A_n$ open?

Comment: I edited it. Look above